# SharePoint version for development for alot of Automated Process Workflows and WebParts?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, version

*I am new to SharePoint and appreciate any guidance. Thanks in advance.*

I have been asked to look into developing a SharePoint platform that would contain web parts and integrated with many automated processes, for work.

I started learning SP2016 capabilities however now I have been informed that as time progresses, we will have create an SharePoint Online version as well, giving the final product to customers with the choice of on premise or cloud.

I noticed that SP2013 can be migrated to Online easily.

My questions are :

1. If we want to develop something as I have mentioned at the beginning, would it be a good idea to develop it with SP-Online then create an On-Premise version as well? Are there major limitation to the Online version,or vice-versa
2. And if we choose to develop on-premise solely, then which version is the safest - 2013,2016, 2019?
3. Also is there a development version without having to renew the license few months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are limitations with the Online product with regards to customization, it sounds like customization could be a show stopper for you.  If so than I would recommend the On-Prem version where it is easier to write custom code etc.  For on-prem use SP2019, there is no reason to start off with an old version that you will need to update in a few years.  I'm not aware of a dev version that does not expire.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my queries.